# How to fix undefined is not a function listing the state in the render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have problem regarding listing all the details of the users, I don't understand why the error shows that my mapping is undefined is not a function. I create a function which inside the function are the list of users so after i list the users, then I put it on the render, however the mapping shows that  undefined function..

I will show you guys the sample code that I already made:

**Constructor:**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      driver_id:'',
      driver_history_list:[]
    }

    this.renderCardHistoryList = this.renderCardHistoryList.bind(this);
  }
```

**Mount:**

```
async componentDidMount() {
  NavigationBar.setColor('white')
  NavigationBar.setStatusBarColor('#008E9B',true)
  NavigationBar.setStatusBarTheme('white',true)
  const ids_driver =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('IDS');     
  axios.get('http://192.168.100.111:8001/api/driver_history/'+ids_driver)
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      driver_history_list:response
   })
  }).catch(function(error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
  })
}
```

**Function:**

```
renderCardHistoryList() {

      const history_list = Array.isArray(this.state.driver_history_list) && this.state.driver_history_list || [];

      return history_list.map(driver_info => {
        return (
          <Card>
            <CardItem header button onPress={() => alert("This is Card Header")}>
              <Left style={{flex:1}}>

              </Left>
              <Right>
                <Text style={{fontSize:15}}>12 May 2019, 08:46pm</Text>
              </Right>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem button onPress={() => alert("This is Card Body")}>
              <Body style={{bottom:'6%',position:'relative'}}>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                  <Icon type="MaterialCommunityIcons" name='store' style={{fontSize:20,color:'#0a60ff'}}/>
                  <Text style={{marginLeft:'5%',fontSize:14}}>Store 1790</Text>
                </View>

                <Icon type="Entypo" name='dots-two-vertical' style={{fontSize:12,marginLeft:'1%',color:'grey',marginTop:'1%'}}/>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center',marginTop:'1%' }}>
                  <Icon type="MaterialCommunityIcons" name='map-marker-radius' style={{fontSize:20,color: "#f92223"}} />
                  <Text style={{marginLeft:'5%',fontSize:14}}></Text>
                </View>

                <Icon type="Entypo" name='dots-two-vertical' style={{fontSize:12,marginLeft:'1%',color:'grey',marginTop:'1%'}}/>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center',marginTop:'1%' }}>
                  <Icon type="Ionicons" name='ios-checkmark-circle' style={{fontSize:20,color: "#FF9501"}} />
                  <Text style={{marginLeft:'5%',fontSize:14}}></Text>
                </View>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        )
      })
    }
```

**Render:**

```
render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header style={{backgroundColor:'#008E9B'}}>
          <Left style={{flex:1}}>
              <Button transparent>
                  <Icon name='arrow-back' />
              </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body style={{ flex: 1,  justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <Title>History</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right style={{flex: 1}} />
        </Header>
        <Content padder>
          {this.renderCardHistoryList()}
        </Content>
      </Container>
    )
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Result 1]

[image: Result on response]

Comment: Try rmoving return that's before this.state.driver_history_list.map...

Comment: @vitomadio that won't help.

Comment: @vitomadio your suggestion is not working. thanks

Comment: You'll have to show where you set the value of that state variable (`driver_history_list`).

Comment: @JJJ please see my new update thanks

Comment: Ok, and now you'll have to do `console.log(response)` to see what the server returns.

Comment: @JJJ i cant show any logs on my console

Comment: @JJJ but i get the the result on api..

Comment: @JJJ if i use alert(JSON.stringify(response)); the data is showing..

Comment: Uh ok, *what* is it showing?

Comment: @JJJ take a look on my new update thanks

Comment: Well that's an object instead of an array, isn't it? You need to do `this.setState({ driver_history_list: response.data })` to get the array. And for the love of all that's holy, start using the debugger instead of alerts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate your array. `const history_list= this.state.driver_history_list || [];`

```
renderCardHistoryList() {

  const history_list = Array.isArray(this.state.driver_history_list) && this.state.driver_history_list || [];

  return history_list.map(driver_info => {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardItem header button onPress={() => alert("This is Card Header")}>
          <Left style={{flex:1}}>

          </Left>
          <Right>
            <Text style={{fontSize:15}}>12 May 2019, 08:46pm</Text>
          </Right>
        </CardItem>
        <CardItem button onPress={() => alert("This is Card Body")}>
          <Body style={{bottom:'6%',position:'relative'}}>

            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
              <Icon type="MaterialCommunityIcons" name='store' style={{fontSize:20,color:'#0a60ff'}}/>
              <Text style={{marginLeft:'5%',fontSize:14}}>Store 1790</Text>
            </View>

            <Icon type="Entypo" name='dots-two-vertical' style={{fontSize:12,marginLeft:'1%',color:'grey',marginTop:'1%'}}/>

            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center',marginTop:'1%' }}>
              <Icon type="MaterialCommunityIcons" name='map-marker-radius' style={{fontSize:20,color: "#f92223"}} />
              <Text style={{marginLeft:'5%',fontSize:14}}></Text>
            </View>

            <Icon type="Entypo" name='dots-two-vertical' style={{fontSize:12,marginLeft:'1%',color:'grey',marginTop:'1%'}}/>

            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center',marginTop:'1%' }}>
              <Icon type="Ionicons" name='ios-checkmark-circle' style={{fontSize:20,color: "#FF9501"}} />
              <Text style={{marginLeft:'5%',fontSize:14}}></Text>
            </View>
          </Body>
        </CardItem>
      </Card>
    )
  })
}
```

**EDIT**

you are setting the whole response to driver_history_list, which is an object change it to.

```
driver_history_list: response.data
```

**NOTE**

Always validate your data. Don't assume that you'll always get the right data. When working with objects always validate them, as doing `data.name`, can break your app, if `data` is null or undefined. for example, given the following object.

```
const animal = {};
```

doing

```
// throws an error, Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
console.log(animal.name.toLowerCase())
```

to prevent that from happening, we need to check if the propery exists, like the following.

```
// checks if the name property exists console name, else assign a console log 'Lion'
console.log(animal.name && animal.name.toLowerCase() || 'Lion')
```

Comment: undefined is not a function history_list.map

Comment: @DevGe I'm pretty sure you're setting the value to an object instead of an array but again, you'll have to show where you set it (and preferably a `console.log` of its value) for anyone to be able to give a definite answer.

Comment: @JJJ sure i will update my post, i will include the componentsMount

Comment: @DevGe I've upated my answer.

Comment: @JuniusL. the error not shown, but the return of list is not render to the application, no result

Comment: but the request seems to fail, in your screenshot?

Comment: @JuniusL. hmm.. there is no error.. but there is no result render

Comment: the alert shown from your screenshot is in `catch` block, which suggest that your request failed.

Comment: @JuniusL. wait i will update my post so better understand well

Comment: @JuniusL. hi, please see my new update. there is no result on my application

Comment: set your array to `driver_history_list: response.data`